# Нужно вывести средний рейтинг комментариев. Есть таблица id username email coments rating

Tags: php

index.php

```
 <?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=coment', 'root', '');

require 'insert.php';
 require 'read.php';

?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="" method="post">

             <p>
                <label for="user">Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="username">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="email">E-mail :</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="comment">Comment :</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
            </p>
           <p>
                <label for="qt_1">1</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="qt_1">

                <label for="qt_2">2</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"  id="qt_2">
                <label for="qt_3">3</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"  id="qt_3">
                <label for="qt_4">4</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"  id="qt_4">
                <label for="qt_5">5</label>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="qt_5">
            </p>
              <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

read.php

```
    <?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments';

$result = $pdo->query($query);

foreach ($result as $comment) {
    ?>
    <p>
    <div>
        <strong><?php echo $comment['username'] ?></strong>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span><?php echo $comment['email'] ?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><?php echo $comment['comment'] ?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><?php echo $comment['rating'] ?></span>
    </div>
    </p>




}
```

insert.php

```
        <?php

    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $query =
            'INSERT INTO comments (username, email, comment, rating) VALUES ("'. $_POST['username'] . '", "' . $_POST['email'] . '", "'. $_POST['comment'] .'","'. $_POST['rating'] .'")';

        $pdo->query($query)

;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто использовать запрос с [AVG](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-avg/):

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as rating from comments;
```

Вызываете его через свой класс для работы с БД и забираете ответ.